# Table indexes/pk for Optimistic Locking in JPA

Tags: java, database, jpa, versioning, optimistic-locking

What is the best practice for defining table indexes for entities supporting optimistic locking?

For sure, entity id has to be part of some index in DB to enable fast lookups by id. What about version column? Does it make sense to make it part of an index?

What if we do not define DB primary key, but create an index consisting of entity id + version column? Any risk of having two rows in DB with same entity id? Say two transactions persist two entities with the same entity id in parallel?

Comment: Your question meanders quite a bit and makes me wonder what problem you are really trying to solve. But regardless of the problem, removing primary keys should definitely ***NOT*** be on your list of possible solutions.

Comment: My main concern is whether not having DB primary key corresponding to entity id can do any harm when optimistic locking is used. I think the answer is yes. Say, two threads are trying to persist entity with the same entity id in parallel. Even if they execute find(), both of them may fail to find any entry in db corresponding to entity id and both will try to insert data into DB. PK would have guarded against this scenario. Therefore it is mandatory.

Comment: So, you are executing concurrent inserts to the database with potentially conflicting primary keys? You should probably redefine your key generator, or use an auto-incrementing id. In any case, your database will serialize the inserts and after the first successful transaction is committed all subsequent ones with the same id will fail.

Comment: I use composite primary key, it is not generated.

Comment: Ok, so you cant auto-generate your primary keys, but the fact remains, the database will ensure that no two items can be inserted with the same primary key (simple or compound). This is a *guarantee* that is provided at the database level.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have an entity defined with a version column as follows:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity implements Serializable {    

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @Version
    private Long version;

    //...
}
```

On update, the field annotated with `@Version` will be incremented and added to the WHERE clause, for example:

```
UPDATE MYENTITY SET ..., VERSION = VERSION + 1 WHERE ((ID = ?) AND (VERSION = ?))
```

As you can see, the version column is used in the `WHERE` clause, but so is the ID column (which has an index on it already as it is the primary key), so **I don't think you would see much benefit in adding an index to the VERSION column**.